Kubernetes Gitlab Runner - Gitlab Jobs using System:Anonymous account instead of specified service account
I have a Kubernetes cluster with a namespace called "gitlab-runner" which contains service account "runner-service" rolebinded to allow access to create/destroy nodes and read secrets. I intend for the gitlab-runner application to use this account, so I have it specified in the deployment YAML and config.toml:
job error output
#snippet from deplyoment.yaml    
apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: gitlab-runner
      namespace: gitlab-runner
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: gitlab-runner
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: gitlab-runner
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: runner-service
          containers:
          - name: gitlab-runner
            image: nexus:44301/gitlab/gitlab-runner:v15.8.0
            volumeMounts:


#Snippet from config.toml
[runners.kubernetes]
host = "https://10.1.18.17:6443"
bearer_token_overwrite_allowed = false
image = "nexus:8201/docker:20.10.13-dind"
namespace = "gitlab-runner"
namespace_overwrite_allowed = ""
namespace_per_job = false
node_selector_overwrite_allowed = ""
node_tolerations_overwrite_allowed = ""
pod_labels_overwrite_allowed = ""
service_account = "runner-service"
service_account_overwrite_allowed = ""
pod_annotations_overwrite_allowed = ""
[runners.kubernetes.volumes]

The service account "runner-service" is obviously being used through the runner pod (through kubectl describe and kubectl exec) and the bearer token is deployed within the pod at: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token. I can then manually use that token to curl the error URL from within the gitlab-runner container.
Output from describe command: 
Name:             gitlab-runner-676886cd99-mxjf9
Namespace:        gitlab-runner
Priority:         0
Service Account:  runner-service
Node:             node/10.1.74.27
Start Time:       Tue, 16 Jul 2024 12:45:36 -0400
Labels:           app=gitlab-runner
                  pod-template-hash=676886cd99 
Annotations:      cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: 974ce47411ad8f06749b1674fdec38c091e532426eea1ae18d078b563e39c34f
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 192.168.167.171/32
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 192.168.167.171/32
Status:           Running
IP:               192.168.167.171
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.167.171
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/gitlab-runner-676886cd99
Containers:
  gitlab-runner:

You can see that the correct account is available, so why aren't the jobs using the correct account? Do I have to authenticate from .gitlab-ci.yaml side? Thank you for any help, please let me know what more info is needed.
